# How are controller instantiated? Are they user session specific as well?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to know these things about the life span of a controller

1. Is it user session specific?
2. What is the life span of the controller?
3. When is it instantiated and when does it get destroyed/garbage collected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it user session specific?

> Not sure, what you mean by user session specific.

what is the life span of the controller?

> It gets instantiated after the routing is completed. See details
>   [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varunm/archive/2013/10/03/understanding-of-mvc-page-life-cycle.aspx)

When is it instantiated and when does it get destroyed/garbage collected?

> The ASP.NET MVC framework calls Dispose when the request has completed
>   processing. Developers typically do not have to call Dispose. If you
>   derive a class from Controller and the derived class uses unmanaged
>   memory, managed operating-system resources (such as files), or COM
>   objects, you should implement Dispose to clean up these resources. You
>   should also call the Dispose method of the base class. The Dispose
>   method leaves the Controller instance in an unusable state. After you
>   call Dispose, you must release all references to the Controller
>   instance so that the garbage collector can reclaim the memory that the
>   Controller instance was occupying.

Comment: Hi Ehsan, when i say user session specific, it really means: "does it instantiated a new controller when a new user hits the URL. And only that particular user can access this controller as long as his/her session lives". Thanks!

Comment: Then the answer is Yes